# How can you implement a fixed header, and animations like slide, in an HTML5 web app for the iPhone (like Google Music does)?

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications, animation, css

I just saw http://music.google.com which is an HTLM5 webapp.

I'm wondering, how it is possible to fix the header ? And use animations like slide with an iPhone etc... ? It seems to be like an iPhone native app !

Any help, please ?

PS: Without jQuery Mobile, thanks

Comment: What's wrong with jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Google don't use jQuery Mobile.

Comment: So if it isnt good enough for google then it isnt good enough for everyone else?

Answer (score 1):

use this http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4. 
This is well tested and working on our lot of mobile applications.
You can try their demo too. http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/

Answer (score 0):

You’ve kind of got two questions there, but:

1. The CSS declaration `position: fixed` is supported by Safari on iOS 5 (see e.g. http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5), but not earlier.

   I’m not sure how you achieve a fixed header on earlier versions of iOS.
2. Safari supports (and I think invented) CSS [transitions](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Transitions/Transitions.html) and [animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Animations/Animations.html).

   I believe they take advantage of iOS’s built-in animation libraries, so they should work much better than attempting to do the same thing via JavaScript.

Comment: Yep, Safari supports position fixed, but I don't use iOS5. I am in 4.3. And on an Android smartphone, the header is fixed too. Have seen Google music on Android or iPhone ?

Comment: @Steffi: aha. I haven’t I’m afraid — it’s only available in the US at the moment, and I’m in the UK.

Comment: I'm in France and I have it. You just need an invitation

Comment: @Steffi: fair enough. When I go to the url you provided, it says “Music Beta is currently only available in the United States”. My experience ends there.

Answer (score 0):

What it boils down to is the following on mobile web.  You can NOT do "position:fixed", so instead you must create a div that you will scroll the contents yourself.

1) Create the header div and set the position to absolute.  Set a height/width.

2) Create a second div (content div) that is the height/width (generally the rest of the page).  What you then need to do is find a scrolling tool.  Check out https://github.com/appMobi/aUX_web for aUX_webScroller  .  Since you are scrolling the second div, the header will stay fixed in position.

Ian